# Intermittent DNS resolution problems

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-7

Of ~140 PCs, a few PCs (no determined pattern) are consistently unable to resolve the AD DS domain name during boot and intermittently unable to resolve AD DS DNS names post-boot. This can be temporarily resolved by restarting the Windows service `DNS Client` / `dnscache` and/or rebooting the PC until it works.

My diagnostic progress:

1. Once the resolution is in place, both domain controllers are contactable (verified in multiple ways) and Group Policy does apply but some policies require a reboot, hence this problem.
2. The NIC's DNS configuration (servers, etc) are correct.
3. Command `nltest /DSQUERYDNS` outputs `I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 50 0x32 ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`.
4. Command `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` outputs `True`.
5. Updating the network device `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller`'s device driver from version 7.86.508.2014 / 2014/05/08 to version 7.107.323.2017 / 2017/03/23 didn't make a difference.
6. `\\<%logonServer%>\NETLOGON\` is accessible.
7. Enabling local policy `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon` didn't make a difference.
8. No traffic is blocked by the firewall during reboot.

As far as I'm aware, this only started happening since the site migration onto a new, restricted, VLAN-ed network so I can't help but suspect the Sophos XG 210 UTM but that doesn't make sense because it was firewall- / routing-related then I'd expect the problem to be much more consistent and widespread.

**Update 2017/07/07 16:26**

My diagnostic progress:

9. Updating the Sophos XG firmware from version 16.05.3 MR-3 to version 16.05.5 MR-5 didn't resolve the problem.
10. Created a network firewall rule to allow LAN-to-any, PC's IP address-to-any using any ports / services didn't resolve the problem.
11. Disabling IPv6 on the NIC and rebooting didn't resolve the problem.
12. Executing elevated command `netsh int ip reset reset.log` and rebooting didn't resolve the problem.
13. Logging on using a freshly-generated local user profile didn't resolve the problem.

**Update 2017/07/12 11:23**

The problem has changed on the test PC that I'm using. Post-boot, pinging the AD domain name and any server hostname successfully resolves and transmits **but** RSoP still reports that computer-side (not user-side) Group Policy Infrastructure failed to apply because `The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted`.

My diagnostic progress:

14. Reconfiguring the NIC setting almost the exact same configuration (IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, and DNS servers) statically, rather than dynamically, consistently resolved the boot, computer-side Group Policy problem on two of the affected PCs. I'm going to leave this static config in place for a few days to see if it resolves the intermittent DNS resolution problem too.

**Update 2017/07/13 13:28**

The intermittent DNS resolution problem recurred

My diagnostic progress:

15. Pinging FQDNs with trailing `.`s didn't make a difference.
16. Reconfiguring the NIC setting the **exact** same configuration (IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, DNS servers, and connection-specific DNS suffix) statically resolved the problem, albeit probably temporary.
17. I've posted a V7 USB3-to-Ethernet adapter to test whether it's an incompatibility between the onboard NIC and the switches or something. Results tomorrow.

**Update 2017/08/03 14:51:**

10+ hours of diagnostics later, the root cause seems to be MAX RemoteManagement's / MSP Remote Management's RMM agent (likely sub-component Advanced Monitoring Agent Network Management) as we uninstalled it on a few affected PCs on 2017/07/25 and the problems haven't recurred since.

Comment: What event id's did you get? Maybe you have a problem with autoneg, what says the switchport? Is `portfast` enabled?

Comment: @duenni The event IDs that I took notice of were 8021, 1055, and 5719. The switches are actually managed by a different third-party so I don't have much information on that but they said that they can't see anything untoward in the logs or configuration.

Comment: Check that your dhcp lease time matches with your scavenging settings. Your DNS server may not be allowing updates for a certain period of time as well. Are the dns servers on a different VLAN than your PCs? Are VLANs being allowed to communicate with each other?

Comment: @veel84 This particular PC actually has a DHCP reservation. Yes, the DCs and PCs are on different VLANs but the firewall allows the required ports as confirmed with packet captures.

Comment: Can a PC with the problem ping the IP of DNS? If it can Open a telnet session on one with the problem to check that the DNS port is accessible. Or use nmap on a problem pc to scan DNS for open ports.

Comment: @veel84 `nslookup` works. That's the same thing, right?

Comment: It's all part of a troubleshooting process, trust but verify...So the problem PCs can resolve DNS names? Can your DNS server resolve names?

Comment: @veel84 Yes but intermittently and only once the temporary resolution is in place. Yes, they can.

Comment: When they cannot, can you try some of the tools I mentioned? Ping, nmap, telnet to dns port #.

Comment: @veel84 For the affected DNS names, `ping` reports `Ping request could not find host` but `nslookup` resolves correctly. Restarting the DNS Client service temporarily resolves the problem.

Comment: @mythofechelon when you ping, do you ping short name or FQDN? It's very interesting if nslookup works but not ping FQDN.

Comment: @strongline Good question. I've been using random server hostnames and the AD domain name which usually have the same results but it is intermittent / random.

Comment: @mythofechelon you might want to reset winsock as well "netsh winsock reset" . By pinging FQDN (with an ending dot) so it uses explicite suffix in order to rule out search suffix issues.

Comment: You may need to provide a network diagram for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly confident in saying that this was caused by MAX RemoteManagement's / MSP Remote Management's RMM agent as uninstalling it has resolved a wide variety of DNS- / network-related problems on different PCs in different locations.